# I need to echo PHP variable in a JavaScript

Tags: php

My code is

```
$selectedWallet = $_POST['wallet'];
  <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                     var oMain = new CMain({
                                    win_occurrence: 40,
                                    min_bet: 1,
                                    max_bet: 300,
                                    bet_time: 10000,
                                    money: "<?php echo $SelectedWallet; ?>",                 //STARING CREDIT FOR THE USER
                                    blackjack_payout: 1.5,
                                    game_cash: 500,
                                    fullscreen:true,
                                    check_orientation:true,
                                });
</script>
```

I need to echo a PHP variable in this script i.e. money: "

Comment: What you have done is right. What do you get for `var_dump($SelectedWallet);`?

Comment: It's a typo: `$selectedWallet` is not `$SelectedWallet`! Please don't answer this and close it as typo.

Comment: This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Use this, you are taking value in one variable and echoing undefined variable.

```
$selectedWallet = $_POST['wallet'];
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                 var oMain = new CMain({
                                win_occurrence: 40,
                                min_bet: 1,
                                max_bet: 300,
                                bet_time: 10000,
                                money: '<?php echo $selectedWallet; ?>',                 //STARING CREDIT FOR THE USER
                                blackjack_payout: 1.5,
                                game_cash: 500,
                                fullscreen:true,
                                check_orientation:true,
                            });
 </script>
```

Comment: Guys, seriously, it is not a good idea to add answers for a typo instead of closing it.